# HScrollbar/VScrollbar in the Groupbox to group multiple buttons in MFC

Tags: mfc, scrollbar, groupbox

I tried to include the VScrollbar/ HScrollbar. where i have placed the group of static text control[ i have to place around 10 static text ] in the group. But i unable to do.Even I will be happy if you can able to suggest any other way to place the Text control's and can be able to implement the scrollbar

I am using VS 2013 professional.

Thanks

Comment: You need to elaborate your question. As it stands here it is hard to understand what you want.

Comment: MS recommends to use CWnd's build-in scrollbars,  Using CScrollbar is not recommended for scrolling dialogs and controls. From experience, I have to concur. Hopefiully this tidbit will help.  There is not much else we can do with the info you're giving us, except sending you some encouragement.

Comment: A groupbox usually does not contain any other controls. Those are siblings of the groupbox. The containment is of visual nature only. If you need a host window with scrolling functionality, use a [CScrollView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cscrollview-class).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I feel sorry for not replying for your questions.
I implemented using custom draw clistctrl.

My job is to group list of static control and change the color based on the condition.

Initially I thought I should create individual control for everything and change the color based on the color control. 
But I got the idea that how to use the clistctrl for my use.

Now I place all the texts in clistctrl and changing the color based on the condition.

Thanks